# Enable mock location for certain apps on android 6, flyme 5.2

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-location

I'm trying to enable mock locations on my phone and it's not working.
This is my phone's info:
Model: Meizu PRO 6
Android version 6.0
build number: Flyme 5.2.0.0G

The app in which I'm trying to enable mock location for (Fake GPS) keeps asking me to enable mock locations, in which I have enabled, but it just won't work (app keeps asking me to enable it).
this is a photo of my developer settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flyme 5.2.0.0G for Meizu Pro 6 has a bug. I installed chinese version Flyme 5.2.1.1A and it fixed it for me.